# Can OpenVPN clients access the resources of the server? And if so, how?

Tags: openvpn, ubuntu-14.04

Here is my setup, I have a server and clients all running ubuntu and all have openvpn installed on them.  If I were to use a client to login to the openvpn server, would there be any way I would access the resources for the user I just logged into?  Example:  If, from the client, I log into the local user account "client1", would I be able to remotely access/manipulate any of the files that belonged to client1 on the server side?  If so, how would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could only access services and files they owned through a service like FTP or SSH for example. If all you have is a vanilla server with just openvpn installed and those services are disabled then they have no way to access files on that server by normal means.

However, OpenVPN does have an option that allows connected clients to work/connect together as if they are on a local network together. You may want to disable that from the context of your question.